# Inline images in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to insert inline image in my org file in emacs. I am completely new to emacs and org-mode. I searched in google but could not find immediate solution.
If anyone knows how to display inline images in the same buffer in org-mode emacs, please share.

Answer (score 65):

if you add `[[myimage.png]]`, org mode will use the file `myimage.png` as an inline image for myimage.png. You can then run `M-x org-display-inline-images` to display your inline image.

adding

```
(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)
```

to your `.emacs` will make image inlined on opening a org buffer. `M-x
org-redisplay-inline-images` will refresh inlined image if needed.

You could also add

```
#+STARTUP: inlineimages
```

to an org file for inlining images only in this file.

Comment: For that, you also need an Emacs capable of displaying images (such as PNG, for example). Under Windows, that means you need to add some DLL in its bin directory.

Comment: @Remi: Your solution worked and I am able to display images in same buffer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is there a way to enable this on a per file basis?

Comment: you can add #+STARTUP: inlineimages or #+STARTUP: noinlineimages in a org file for enabling (or disabling) on a per file basis.

Comment: Can you resize the inline image? If I add `#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.10in`, the image goes in its own paragraph and not inline any more.

Comment: if the image doesn't display, don't forget to check your current directory ` M-x cd `, since the relative path will be resolved against it.

Comment: how to automatically scale the image to be a certain width?

Answer (score 29):

You can use [org-download](https://github.com/abo-abo/org-download)
to drag images from the web browser or your file system straight to an `org-mode` buffer.

Comment: This is very cool. Thanks.

Comment: I've installed `org-download` and reloaded `.emacs`. If I drag an image from the web onto an `*.org` buffer, it opens a new buffer.