# How to always show inline images?

Tags: image, emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to work with inline images (e.g. for plotting data by gnuplot), and have the problem: images always inserted as *links* by default. I need to do some keypresses to "force" emacs to show *actual image* inline, instead of just file link.

E.g. I start with gnuplot code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC gnuplot :file plot.png
plot sin(x)
#+END_SRC
```

When I press `C-c C-c` on this code block, it runs, and shows me results as link to image file:

```
#+RESULTS:
[[file:plot.png]]
```

- If I press `C-c C-x C-v` (org-toggle-inline-images) twice -- link does replaced with inline image
- If I run `M-x org-redisplay-inline-images` -- again, link does replaced with image
- If I run `(org-display-inline-images t t)` -- again, image is shown

and so on (those options were taken from [Emacs org-display-inline-images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621495/emacs-org-display-inline-images) and [Inline images in org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129338/inline-images-in-org-mode) questions)

But I don't want to press anything special: I want images to be displayed inline by default. I've found and tried following variables:

- `(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)` in `.emacs` config
- `#+STARTUP: inlineimages` header
- `(setq org-display-inline-images t)`

But neither got me the behavior I want. I'm puzzled -- do I want something so unnatural?

P.S. Im' using GNU Emacs v26.1 on MacOS X, org mode v9.1.9-65, if it matters

P.P.S. Although it seems like a bug in my emacs/orgmode version, and I'm yet to report it, but meanwhile I've found following trick: `(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'org-display-inline-images 'append)` (thanks to [ob-ipython](https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython) authors) -- it fixes issue for me right now. Maybe will be useful for somebody else

Comment: I cannot reproduce, Debian / Emacs v26.1 / Org 9.1.2 (C-c C-c shows me the image directly)

Comment: So, looks like it is specific to MacOS build or orgmode version. Thanks for trying

Comment: Maybe. It works out of the box with my config. Note that I do not have exactly the same org mode version. You are welcome.

Comment: @BegemoT Run `M-x org-version` to see what emacs uses

Comment: @VanLaser "org mode v9.1.9-65" (it was in PS)

Comment: Exact same issue on Linux Mint/ emacs 26.3 / Org 9.4. Thanks heaps for the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem with:

```
Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /home/xyz/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20190415/)
```

Reproduction:

1. Start Emacs 26.3 with `emacs -Q`.
2. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `load-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `org` <kbd>RET</kbd>
3. Add `Gnuplot` to `org-babel-load-languages` via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option`.
4. Load [`gnuplot.el`](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/gnuplot/blob/master/gnuplot.el)
5. Open the Org file with the following content and press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> on the source block.

```
#+STARTUP: inlineimages
Some text.

#+BEGIN_SRC gnuplot :file plot.png :results graphics
plot sin(x)
#+END_SRC
```

I have a similar solution as you suggested in your question, but a bit more differentiated.

Re-displaying images in large Org documents can take some time. So I do it only if the source block has the results-parameter [`graphics`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/0d6c51320d8066db867aae0e623d9731c69121ed/lisp/org/ob-core.el#L715-L717):

```el
(require 'subr-x)
(defun org+-babel-after-execute ()
  "Redisplay inline images after executing source blocks with graphics results."
  (when-let ((info (org-babel-get-src-block-info t))
         (params (org-babel-process-params (nth 2 info)))
         (result-params (cdr (assq :result-params params)))
         ((member "graphics" result-params)))
    (org-display-inline-images)))

(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook #'org+-babel-after-execute)
```

Comment: I can still reproduce the problem with Org mode version 9.5.2 on macOS. :(

Answer (score 2):

@Tobias is the best answer.  I have tweaked the @Tobias code to further optimize by bounding the re-display to the current subtree and setting the REFRESH parameter to t to redisplay only if necessary.

```
  (require 'subr-x)
  (defun org+-babel-after-execute ()
    "Redisplay inline images in subtree if cursor in source block with :result graphics."

    (when (org-in-src-block-p)
      (let (beg end)
        (save-excursion
          (org-mark-subtree)
          (setq beg (point))
          (setq end (mark)))
        (when-let ((info (org-babel-get-src-block-info t))
                   (params (org-babel-process-params (nth 2 info)))
                   (result-params (cdr (assq :result-params params)))
                   ((member "graphics" result-params)))
          (org-display-inline-images nil t beg end)))))

  (add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook #'org+-babel-after-execute)
```